How to extract a list of a Firefox profile's add-ons' source URIs (or names)?
Request
I'm looking for a (presumably JSON) file which includes a list of all installed add-ons. Firefox surely retains one.
Ideally, I want it to contain solely the names of the installed add-ons, but I don't expect this to be available by default.
Rationale
I want to be able to export this list so that when reporting web and/or extension (in)compatibility issues, I can easily demonstrate which combinations of add-ons cause which effects.
It shall replace my current method of achieving this:

Invoke firefox 'about:addons'.
Save the page using Firefox's native feature. ^Citation
Invoke the resultant HTML file within the parent directory as its corresponding sidecar directory (in which its resources are separately stored).
Save that page as a single HTML file with SingleFile.


Have you looked in "about:support", clicked the button in the "Profile Folder" section, and looked to see if the addons.json file is what you want?

Just be aware that addons.json is just a list, and doesn't contain the add-on itself, nor data (e.g., Feedbro might have hundreds of RSS feeds cached). For your purposes, that should be ideal.

@AndrewMorton, that indeed does provide a more visually concise table, but copying the data isn't much easier. In fact, I can't even copy the HTML view-source: markup, because it's dynamically created.

@DrMoishePippik, that was what I was looking for (especially because since it's JSON, it's easier to convert to an HTML table and visualise) but it does include a lot of unnecessary information. Luckily, it's a lot easier to parse to get just the names from programmatically. I'll post an answer that does that if I manage it.

Unfortunately, a mere list of add-on names doesn't appear to be provided by Firefox itself. However, a per-profile PowerShell script using the addons.json file referenced in a comment works:
#!/usr/bin/env -S pwsh
#Requires -PSEdition Core
#Requires -Version 7.4

If ([OperatingSystem]::IsLinux() -EQ $True) {
    $FirefoxProfile = Read-Host # `fimaebr1.default-release-1720105233406`, as an example.
    $AddOnsJSON = Get-Content -LiteralPath "$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/$FirefoxProfile/addons.json"
    $AddOnsHashTable = $AddOnsJSON | ConvertFrom-JSON
    $HashedAddOns = @()

    ForEach ($AddOn in $AddOnsHashTable.addons) {
            $AddOnDetails = [ordered]@{
                    SourceURI = $AddOn.sourceURI
                    Type = $AddOn.type
            }
            $HashedAddOns += [PSCustomObject]$AddOnDetails
    }

    $HashedAddOns | Format-Table -AutoSize
}

If you have need to convert it to a Markdown Table (like I do) you might consider the undermentioned useful too:

Function ConvertTo-MarkDownTable {
    [CmdletBinding()] param(
            [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeLine = $True)] $InputObject
    )
    Begin { $Index = 0 }
    Process {
            if ( !$Index++ ) {
                    '|' + ($_.PSObject.Properties.Name -Join '|') + '|'
                    '|' + ($_.PSObject.Properties.ForEach({ '-' }) -Join '|') + '|'
            }
            '|' + ($_.PSObject.Properties.Value -Join '|') + '|'
    }
}

$HashedAddOns | ConvertTo-MarkDownTable


Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way to ascertain whether they're enabled or not, which does matter.
